# What is a Windows Service and how does its lifecycle differ from a "standard" EXE?

Tags: windows-services

I found the following answer to that question:

*A service opens before you even get to the login screen, whereas a standard exe cannot open until after you have logged on.*

Just i want to verify the answer is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a services *typically* runs the from system boot up to shutdown, and is idependant of logon/off.  so yes, your understanding is reasonably correct.

Comment: actually for that matter, a service is not a different type of .exe, it is just launched differently.